# Why do i get 'g.call is not a function' error in ramda?

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

So I have a problem, I have two functions in ramda.js, they look like this:

```
const getDayName = flip(nth)(['monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday', 'sunday'])

const formatDay = ifElse(isNil, always(''), pipe(dec, getDayName, i18n.t('views.routing.dialogs.${__}')))
```

The first function returns name of the day by it's index, and second accepts id of day, if it's null it returns empty string, otherwise it decreaces id by 1, because index starts from 0 and id starts from 1.

Then it passes it through pipe to getDayName, returns day name, and then uses day name in i18n.t function, which is used for translating day using day name as a key

But I  have a problem, when i use this function i get an error from ramda: g.call is not a function, I think this error comes from the `i18n.t()` in pipe, how could I fix it?

I can't pass arguments in pipe explicitly, like `dayName => ...`, so I should only use `R.__` placeholder from ramda

Comment: What does `i18n.t( ... )` return?

Answer (score 0):

`R.pipe` expects functions, and adding `R.__` to a template string doesn't convert it to a function.

Create a `translate` function that wraps `i18n.t()`, and calls it with the `dayName`:

```
const translate = dayName =>  i18n.t(`views.routing.dialogs.${dayName}`)
```

And use it in the pipe:

```
pipe(dec, getDayName, translate))
```